# Google foobar minion labor shifts challenge

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have a Google foobar challenge:

Write a function called answer(data, n) that takes in a list of less than 100 integers and a number n, and returns that same list but with all of the numbers that occur more than n times removed entirely. The returned list should retain the same ordering as the original list - you don't want to mix up those carefully-planned shift rotations! For instance, if data was [5, 10, 15, 10, 7] and n was 1, answer(data, n) would return the list [5, 15, 7] because 10 occurs twice, and thus was removed from the list entirely.

And this was my answer:

```
def​ ​answer(data=[],​ ​n=0):
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​for​ ​id​ ​in​ ​data:
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​num​ ​=​ ​data.count(id)
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​if​ ​num​ ​>​ ​n:
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​for​ ​i​ ​in​ ​data:
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​if​ ​i​ ​==​ ​id:
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​data.remove​ ​(id)
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​else:
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​continue
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​else:
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​continue
​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​return​ ​data
```

But it didn't pass the test.

Comment: It's unclear what your question is, in fact there is no question here, just your solution. Can you update it please to include it?

Comment: Your algorithm has a `O(N^3)` complexity. This is terrible for a programming challenge like Google FooBar, tests with big data input will likely timeout. Try something else, this can be done in `O(N^2)` (maybe `O(N)`?).

Answer (score 5):

Even shorter

```py
def​ ​solution(data,​ ​n):​
    return [x for x in data if data.count(x) <= n]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one

```
    def solution(data, n): 
        # Your code here
        if len(data) < 100:
            list = filter(lambda a: data.count(a)<= n, data)
            return(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but has not yet received the correct answer. Before looking into the complexity your answer is incorrect. You have to be careful when you want to modify the data structure the loop is dependent on. In your case

```
for i in data:
  if i == _id:
    data.remove(_id)
  else:
    continue
```

will not delete 'id' from 'data' in all cases, because you are changing the length of 'data' along the process and you will skip over some occurrence of 'id' in 'data' when you do this. Instead what you can do is store the index of occurrence of 'id' in the first for loop then delete them in the reverse order in a second 'for loop'.
In your algorithm, the above bug occurs twice (in both of the 'for loops').

Comment: Test case failing data =[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5],n=1

Comment: @Ajithlal the code provided is how not to do the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
def​ ​answer(data=[],​ ​n=0):
    d={}
    for i in data:
        if i not in d:
            d[i] = 1
        else:
            d[i] = d[i]+1

    target=[]
    for i in d.keys():
        if d[i] > n:
            target.append(i) #get those numbers appear counts more than n

    result=[x for x in data if x not in target]
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is the best way to do it. But I had reversed the list to do it. My code is as follows:

```
def solution(data, n):
    # Your code here
    data.reverse()
    for val in data:
        num=data.count(val)
        if(num>n):
            for i in range(num):
              data.remove(val)
        data.reverse()
        return(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this and saw that there are specific conditions that have to be met, such as if there are no matching total numbers that equal n then the entire list is returned. I figured it out this way:

Updated to reflect correct output for the OP's ask

```
def answer(data, n):
    #Append all match count cases in data to bl and eliminate duplicates.
    #For example [5, 10, 15, 10, 7], n = 2, bl = [5, 7, 15]. 
    bl = list(sorted(x for x in data if data.count(x) != n))
    
    #Returns a statement if the list has more than 100 integers within.
    if len(data) > 100:
        return "\nToo many data integers! Data must be below 100 integers."
    #Returns empty list if n = 0.
    if n == 0:
       return bl
    
    #Return list if duplicates were found, otherwise return the original list.
    if bl:
        return bl
    else:
        return data
```

Input:

```
answer([0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5], 2)
```

Output:

```
[0, 3, 3, 3, 4]
```

Comment: This is not about removing duplicates; it's about completely removing those numbers that appear more than `n` times.

Comment: @Gigi You are correct. I changed my response to reflect the ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    data = [2, 3, 2, 5, 6, 2, 5, 1, 8, 9, 9, -9]
    n = 3
    res = answer(data, n)
    print(res)

def answer(data, n):
    store = []
    for x in range(len(data)):
        count = 0
        for y in data:
            if y == data[x]:
                count += 1
        if count > n:
            if data[x] not in store:
                store.append(data[x])

    for z in store:
        for r in reversed(range(len(data))):
            if data[r] == z:
                data.pop(r)
    return data

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution - Duplicate steps will not be traversed

```py
def solution(data, n):
    flag = True
    counter = 0
    length = len(data)
    while flag:
        repeats = data.count(data[counter])
        if repeats > n:
            data = [i for i in data if i != data[counter]]
            length = length - repeats
            counter = 0
        else:
            counter = counter + 1
        if counter == length:
            flag = False
            print(','.join(map(str,data)))
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.
It has passed all of the test cases.

```
def solution(data,n):
workers = data[:99]
for i in workers:
    num_count = data.count(i)
    if num_count > n:
        for t in range(num_count):
            data.remove(i)
    else:
        continue
return data
```

Answer (score -1):

You can answer this by using list comprehensions in one line (not optimal for larger data set):

```
def answer(data, n):
    return [x for x in data if x not in [y for y in set(data) if data.count(y) > n]]
```

Normal way:

```
def answer(data, n):
    data_set = set(data)
    for d in data_set:
        if data.count(d) > n:
            data = filter(lambda a: a != d, data)
    return data
```

Answer (score -1):

Test case failing data =[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5],n=1