# What is my Solution for the assign minions doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

EDIT: I know there are other solutions to this. My question is what am I doing wrong. Where is my logic simple. Nothing else.

Was solving the minions work assignment code in Python.
The question is the following

```
Write a function called solution(data, n) that takes in a list of less than 100 integers and a
number n, and returns that same list but with all of the numbers that occur more than n times
removed entirely. The returned list should retain the same ordering as the original list - you don't want to mix up those carefully planned shift rotations! For instance, if data was [5, 10,
15, 10, 7] and n was 1, solution(data, n) would return the list [5, 15, 7] because 10 occurs 
twice, and thus was removed from the list entirely.
```

My code is the following

```
from collections import OrderedDict
def solution(data, n): 
    # Your code here
    if(len(data)>=100):
        return []
    seen=OrderedDict()
    s=[]
    for i in data:
        if i in seen:
            seen[i]+=1
        else:
            seen[i]=1
    for k in seen:
        if(seen[k]<=n):
            s.append(k)
    return s
```

My logic was to use an ordered dict to keep track of the numbers and the number of times they show up. This way we could do the code in linear time instead of n^2 (by checking the count of every value in data). This worked for most cases but is failing in some. What am I missing? Is there some space constraint? Some overlooked case?

Comment: You can use `collections.Counter` instead of `OrderedDict`

Comment: What is a failing case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google foobar minion labor shifts challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42954739/google-foobar-minion-labor-shifts-challenge)